# When does a webbrowser send If-Modified-Since?

Tags: python, browser, flask, if-modified-since

I'm serving a dynamically created `recent.rss` via python flask and naturally that way it is always sent via `200 OK`. I was going to fix this by setting the header `Expires` a week into the future and checking if the browser sent `If-Modified-Since`.

If so (after comparing dates) I would just do `return nothing, 304` instead of `return response`, but according to Firebug and `request.environ` my browser just never sends `If-Modified-Since` for that ressource.

I know I could just save the data to a file and serve it as a real static file using a webserver, but I might end up really needing to serve static files via WSGI and even if not I'd like to know why this doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See the specs: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[RFC 2616 HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) has this note in [14.25 If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25):

> When handling an `If-Modified-Since` header field, some
>         servers will use an exact date comparison function, rather than a
>         less-than function, for deciding whether to send a 304 (Not
>         Modified) response. To get best results when sending an `If-Modified-Since` header field for cache validation, clients are
>         advised to use the exact date string received in a previous `Last-Modified` header field whenever possible.

This indicates that you should send a `Last-Modified` header when you expect/want the client to send `If-Modified-Since`.

Comment: I also found that with Firefox (v 54) the header was not sent unless both `Last-Modified` and `Expires` were set.